# Retrieve all controller action that have a specific annotation - Symfony2

Tags: symfony, annotations, command

I have created an annotation class called @Module, and a command GenerateModulesCommand. What I want is to find all controller actions that have the @Module annotation.

Example :

```
/**
 * 
 * @Module(name='sidebar', enabled=true')
 */
public function sidebarAction($name) {
    $ape = new ArrayParamsExtension ();
    return $this->render('ModuleManagerBundle:Default:sidebar.html.twig', $ape->getArrayParams($name));
}
```

I want to be able to look at the specific properties in the @Module (name, enabled, etc...)
So far, this is my execute method from my Command :

```
protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output) {
    $path = $this->getApplication()->getKernel()->locateResource('@ModuleManagerBundle');
    $driver = new PHPDriver($path);
    $classes = $driver->getAllClassNames();

    foreach ($classes as $key => $class) {
        $reader = new AnnotationReader();

        $annotationReader = new CachedReader(
                $reader, new ArrayCache()
        );

        $reflClass = new ReflectionClass("\Controller\\" . $reportableClass);
        $annotation = $annotationReader->getClassAnnotation(
                $reflClass, 'Custom_Annotation'
        );
        if (is_null($annotation)) {
            unset($classes[$key]);
        }
    }


    $output->writeln($path);
}
```

I found this code on sof, but I don't know how to search all Controller classes and all the Actions inside them..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this in your function

```
use Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationReader;
```

your function

```
    public function getControllersWithAnnotationModules()
        {
            $allAnnotations = new AnnotationReader();
            $controllers = array();
            foreach ($this->container->get('router')->getRouteCollection()->all() as $route) {
                $defaults = $route->getDefaults();
                if (isset($defaults['_controller'])) {
                    $controllerAction = explode(':', $defaults['_controller']);
                    $controller = $controllerAction[0];
                    if (!isset($controllers[$controller]) && class_exists($controller)) {
                        $controllers[$controller] = $controller;
                    }


                }
            }
            $controllersWithModules = array();
            foreach($controllers as $controller){

                $reflectionClass = new \ReflectionClass($controller);
                $module = $allAnnotations->getClassAnnotation($reflectionClass,'Acme\YourBundle\Module');
                if($module)
                    $controllersWithModules[] = $controller;

            }
            return $controllersWithModules ;

        }
```

Comment: Sorry but can I ask you how to use this function to get the "Actions" that have the annotation @Module? example : indexAction, etc...

Comment: You can add this in your controller, dont forget the "use" then replace this "Acme\YourBundle\Module" by the namespace of your @module, finaly in your indexAction you can call this function $this->getControllersWithAnnotationModules()